# can't install "type": "module" in package.json

Tags: node.js, json

I have some server code that receives data from a json file, the console gives an error about the absence of "type": "module", although it is present in the package.json file.
server code:
[image]

```js
import JsonData from '../email.json' assert { type: "json" };
  const inputemail = JsonData;
  const mysql = require("mysql2");
  //  const inputemail = require('./versions-page')

 const connection = mysql.createConnection({
   host: "****",
   user: "***",
  database: "****",
   password: "****"
 });
 connection.query("SELECT * FROM **** WHERE Email = '" + inputemail + "'",
  function(err, results, fields) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(results); 
  
});
connection.end();
```

[image]